# Is there a way to trigger a random event in Skyrim using console commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to trigger a random event in Skyrim using console commands?

I want to trigger the random encounter "The Drunken Dare".

https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Random_Encounters_(Skyrim)

> An Argonian will approach the Dragonborn and claim that he had been
>   met during "A Night to Remember" during the drunken night with Sam,
>   claiming that he was offered 10,000 gold to break into a bandit camp
>   and steal a hat from the chief. If the Dragonborn does not give him
>   the gold, he will become hostile and attack. He can also be persuaded
>   into only paying 750 gold.

Is there a way to do this through console command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had thought a `setstage` reference would be available, but apparently not. However, since

> they are all random
>   encounters which occur some time after completing a [Daedric quest](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Daedric_Quests_(Skyrim))

it could work to spawn *Deep-In-His-Cups* after finishing a Daedric quest, using the console:

`Prid 000BBDA0` and then `moveto player`.

The Daedric quests can be started through the console if so desired, using `setstage <quest id> <stage value>`, and one of the following ID's:

The Black Star - `DA01Intro`or `DA01`
Boethiah's Call - `DA02`
A Daedra's Best Friend - `DA03`
Discerning the Transmundane - `DA04`
Ill Met by Moonlight - `DA05`
The Cursed Tribe - `DA06`
Pieces of the Past - `DA07`
The Whispering Door - `DA08`
The Break of Dawn - `DA09`
The House of Horrors - `DA10`
The Taste of Death - `DA11Intro` or `DA11`
The Only Cure - `DA13Intro` or `DA13`
The Mind of Madness - `DA15`
Waking Nightmare - `DA16`

<sup>Makes me wonder what `DA12` refers to..</sup>

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: No idea. I hate it too, because it's anonymous and some people do it for no reason.